# How to stop Apache access.log grooving every few seconds?

Tags: apache2, zend

I installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 Server + Zend Server CE (MySQL / PHPmyadmin) from `deb http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/5.6.0_ubuntu1204/deb server non-free  Repository`.

My apache2/access.log looks like this and grooving every few seconds:

```
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:27:59 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:27:59 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:27:59 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:00 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:00 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:00 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:00 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:00 +0200] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 126 "-" "Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:08 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:13 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:18 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:23 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:28 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:33 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:38 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:43 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:48 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:53 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
223.255.255.1 - - [06/Aug/2012:13:28:58 +0200] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "-" "-"
```

Do you know why and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 8):

You need to make some changes in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, specifically:

1. Create some environment tests with `SetEnvIf`, and;
2. Then, use them on the `CustomLog` line. As follows:

   ```
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" dontlog
    SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "::1" dontlog
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*internal dummy connection.*" dontlog

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log vhost_combined env=!dontlog
   ```

   That last line should already be in the file, just without the last bit.

Note that this will set the `dontlog` environment variable if *either* of the 3 `SetEnvIf` conditions are true. To avoid this, well, it's complicated; but [this blog](https://stephane.lesimple.fr/blog/2010-01-28/apache-logical-or-and-conditions-with-setenvif.html) seems to have a solution.

Comment: instead of editing `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` I've edited `/etc/apache2/conf.d/other-vhosts-access-log` because I didn't find "CustomLog" in the first config file. Thanks and hope it helps

Comment: Note one may have to add `LoadModule setenvif_module` and 
`AddModule mod_setenvif.c` to httpd.conf file--ref http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html

Comment: Now it is on `/etc/apache2/conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf`, where _Define an access log for VirtualHosts **that don't define their own logfile**_ (should be a symlink in `conf-enabled`)

Answer (score 2):

This is Apache own doing for keeping processes live.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/InternalDummyConnection

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apache-stop-logging-internal-dummy-connection/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

check here. 
http://www.cathaycenturies.com/blog/?p=420

I think you need modify

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

in order to make it work.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" loopback
CustomLog logs/access_log combined env=!loopback
```

I hope this work you too.